# Error: Updating status requires the extended permission status_update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, facebook

I was using the Old Rest Api in my FAcebook application in cooca. Previously I was able to update status. But now I am getting this error : Error: Updating status requires the extended permission status_update.

I checked in this one http://www.facebook.com/editapps.php?v=allowed  & got that the application is not able to get permission for Posting to my Wall.

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The old rest api has been deprecated and could be killed at any time, with very little notice.  I would use the new Facebook iOS SDK, and request the status_update extended permission from the user.  This is all pretty straight forward by looking at their [sample application](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).